# How to display different values in SQL DEVELOP

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem when displaying a series released in November in two different languages
The problem with WHERE is that I can't combine the 2 conditions with both 2 different languages and the month 11

```
create table views(
name varchar2(1) ,
country varchar2(15),
cname varchar2(1),
type varchar2(15) ,
viewdate date,
primary key(name,country,cname,type,viewdate));


insert into views values('X','Spain', 'A', 'film', '04/10/2022');
insert into views values('X','Spain', 'A', 'film', '08/10/2022');
insert into views values('X','Spain', 'E', 'documentary', '18/10/2022');
insert into views values('Y','Italy', 'B', 'series', '15/10/2022');
insert into views values('Y','Italy', 'B', 'series', '18/10/2022');
insert into views values('Y','Italy', 'B', 'series', '19/10/2022');
insert into views values('Z','Portugal', 'A', 'film', '06/10/2022');
insert into views values('Z','Portugal', 'C', 'series', '01/11/2022');
insert into views values('Z','Portugal', 'D', 'documentary', '30/10/2022');
insert into views values('X','France', 'C', 'series', '02/11/2022');
insert into views values('X','France', 'C', 'series', '03/11/2022');
insert into views values('X','France', 'D', 'documentary', '29/10/2022');`

SELECT cname,type,country,episodes,language,releasedate
FROM content
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM releasedate) = 11
AND
content.TYPE ='series'
AND
SELECT language
FROM content c
Group by language
WHERE c.language != c.language;
```

I should receive 1 empty in the answer

Comment: your insert statements do not work,  if you fix that with a to_date then your select statement does not work.   what are you trying to accomplish I can't tell what you want from your question.  how can c.language != c.language?   that does not make sense.    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4312a9/6

Answer (score 0):

You posted table named `views`, while your query works with a table named `content` whose description seems to be **different** from `views`. If you planned to confuse us, you succeeded.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from views;

N COUNTRY         C TYPE            VIEWDATE
- --------------- - --------------- ----------
X France          C series          02/11/2022
X France          C series          03/11/2022
X France          D documentary     29/10/2022
X Spain           A film            04/10/2022
X Spain           A film            08/10/2022
X Spain           E documentary     18/10/2022
Y Italy           B series          15/10/2022
Y Italy           B series          18/10/2022
Y Italy           B series          19/10/2022
Z Portugal        A film            06/10/2022
Z Portugal        C series          01/11/2022
Z Portugal        D documentary     30/10/2022

12 rows selected.
```

If I understood you correctly, that's what you're looking for - nothing has been returned as there are no rows that satisfy conditions:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM views a
  3   WHERE EXISTS
  4            (  SELECT NULL
  5                 FROM views b
  6                WHERE     b.name = a.name
  7                      AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.viewdate) =
  8                          EXTRACT (MONTH FROM a.viewdate)
  9                      AND b.TYPE = a.TYPE
 10                      AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.viewdate) = 11
 11                      AND b.TYPE = 'series'
 12             GROUP BY b.name
 13               HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT b.country) > 1);

no rows selected
```

But, if we add yet another row related to name `X` which is `series` in `November` but in a country different than `France`, query returns it:

```
SQL>  INSERT INTO views
  2       VALUES ('X',
  3               'Spain',
  4               'D',
  5               'series',
  6               '29/11/2022');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT *
  2    FROM views a
  3   WHERE EXISTS
  4            (  SELECT NULL
  5                 FROM views b
  6                WHERE     b.name = a.name
  7                      AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.viewdate) =
  8                          EXTRACT (MONTH FROM a.viewdate)
  9                      AND b.TYPE = a.TYPE
 10                      AND EXTRACT (MONTH FROM b.viewdate) = 11
 11                      AND b.TYPE = 'series'
 12             GROUP BY b.name
 13               HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT b.country) > 1);

N COUNTRY         C TYPE            VIEWDATE
- --------------- - --------------- ----------
X France          C series          02/11/2022
X France          C series          03/11/2022
X Spain           D series          29/11/2022

SQL>
```